# "Surgeon Simulator 2: Access All Areas requires an active internet connection"

Tags: pc, surgeon-simulator-2

I've tried playing Surgeon Simulator 2 on the PC Game Pass, but every time I launch I get the above message.  I thought maybe their servers were overloaded, but I've been trying for days now with no luck, while my friends are able to launch successfully every time.

There's lots of reports of this problem in the "app reviews", but none of them suggest any fixes.  I clearly am online, since I'm posting this.  **Is there any way to actually play this game?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/Kaazhuma/status/1434153524057759756) suggested changing my DNS to OpenDNS, which, amazingly, actually worked.  Their IP is 208.67.222.222 [(Source)](https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/)

---

Guide on how to do this in Windows 10:

1. Go to the start menu and type "View Network Connections"
2. Right-click your ethernet adapter --> Properties
3. Click *"Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP 4)"*. Click the words themselves, not the checkbox.
4. Click "Properties"
5. In the *"General"* tab, click *"Use the following DNS Server Addresses"*
6. Set your preferred DNS server to `208.67.222.222`

   [image: DNS Settings]
   *(I have Google's DNS set as an "Alternate DNS server" here, which shouldn't be necessary)*
7. Click "ok" a few times.  You should now be able to play the game.

Comment: From a security standpoint, this is horrible; it allows that specific DNS server to redirect any website to anything else. I'd strongly suggest finding out which server name the game is trying to connect to, entering its IP into `\windows\system32\etc\hosts`, and changing DNS back to an official server.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Are you suggesting that Cisco OpenDNS is not an "official" part of the Domain Name System, or is more likely to suffer/perpetrate a DNS hijacking?

Comment: @TimPederick Any DNS provider is just as trustworthy as the company running it. Cisco is *probably* trustworthy, but anybody who tells you "use my DNS, you'll have access to entries you won't have somewhere else" should be approached with caution.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Except [OpenNIC](https://www.opennic.org/), which is great and does all things.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Isn't true for *any* DNS, though? What's an official DNS server?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm there is no "official" DNS server other than the roots, and end-users are not supposed to use those directly. Most people's ISP will provide DNS, which should be pretty efficient, but many people prefer to use Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) or Google (8.8.8.8).

Answer (score 5):

Changing your DNS servers to a public service is a bad idea.

They did some very sloppy implementation of an internet check. The game tries to resolve [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (yes) and public DNS servers answer with 93.184.216.34. Example.com, however, is a reserved domain and should not be used in production (or games). Some modems or ISP's  block it by default.

They will probably fix this soon, but for the time being it's safer to change your hostfile than to change your DNS servers.

1. Open notepad as admin
2. Open  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`  (go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, click "all files" in bottom right (in the textfiles (*.txt) box)  and click the `hosts` file.
3. Add a line under the last line of the text:

   ```
   93.184.216.34     www.example.com
   ```
4. Save the file.

Remove it after they fixed it.

*edit: added some more context.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Not sure why the canned comment above was added, this is a good answer, if a bit technical. It explains the problem (amateur coding in the game) and explains how to fix it without having to change your DNS, which is not something you should be doing willy-nilly without understanding the risks.

Comment: This solution worked for me. To anyone who is having trouble opening the file in notepad as admin like I had, I found that running command prompt as admin and typing in: notepad "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" and then add 93.184.216.34 www.example.com as Sage said.

Comment: I can't seem to find the setting to txt file for the host file.. The only file type I see for the "hosts" file is a "File" type file. Hopefully that makes sense, but I can't seem to figure this out..